# AngularJS app - with Lumen or Laravel?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, architecture, lumen

I am about to build web application consisting of three parts:

1. Public data-oriented websites for unauthenticated users with geolocation search, ...
2. Member area (with authentication) for managing the data
3. Mobile app/apps with the same functionalities

The airbnb.com is a good example of the structure.

Basicaly the thing is to create a server side API which will be shared accross clients.

I definitelly want to use AngularJS for the client side, but I am not sure which of those solutions is better:

1. Create the API with microframework Lumen and add sessions / authentication / html serving / other services to the Lumen
2. Create the API with full stack framework Laravel and serve html to AngularJS

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a solid api, lumen has all we need to build an api. You can go ahead with option 1 as you can later on migrate to full stack laravel framework, if needed.